# User Does not exists in ASP.NET MVC Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, user-interface, user-controls

**Hi,**

I am about to move a big part of a view to a template. This is made to be able to show the content on multiple pages.

The problem is that I have checks in this view on the user object like this :

```
<% if(User.Identity != null && User.Identity.Name.Length > 0) {%>
```

And when placing this in the template view I will get the following exception :

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'User' does not exist in the current context
```

**Pleas advice.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try fetching it from the context:

```
<% if (ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity != null && ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Length > 0) { %>
```